# Resolve javascript promise on DOM event

Tags: javascript, dom, promise

I've been looking for an answer but couldn't find none for my issue (or at least I didn't understand how to make it work for mine.) So I have this function:

```
Test.prototype.testing = function(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = 
      "<button onclick=\"\">Next</button>";
  });
};
```

How can I make the promise resolve on button click? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use innerHTML? That way might be able to get the button to call `resolve` directly?

Comment: a promise of an event?

Comment: I guess you can.  if you create that button using `document.createElement("button")` and then attach on click handler that resolves the promise. it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
function Test() {}

Test.prototype.testing = function(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    const btn = document.createElement("button")
    btn.innerHTML = 'Next'
    btn.addEventListener('click', resolve);
    document.getElementById("element").appendChild(btn)
  });
};

(new Test()).testing()
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. By using the CustomEvent API for the browser environment.

```
function myPromiseReturningFunction() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.addEventListener("myCustomEvent", (event) => {
       resolve(event.detail);
    }) 
  })
}

myPromiseReturningFunction().then(result => {
   alert(result)
})

document.getElementById("element").addEventListener("click", () => {
   window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("myCustomEvent", {detail : "It works!"}))
})
```

```
<p id="element"> Next </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to already have the button in the DOM, and then reference it. At that point it's a simple matter of setting the `onclick` event handler to the resolve function. (You could also use `addEventListener` if you want)

```js
var elBtn = document.getElementById('resolver');
function Test(){ }

Test.prototype.testing = function(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    elBtn.onclick = resolve;
  });
};

var t = new Test();
t.testing().then(x=> {
  console.log('resolved!');
});
```

```html
<button id='resolver'>Click me!</button>
```